# My for loop isn't responding right

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am searching an array. Trying to find a the entry that is 746.

It is the last one in the array and **my for loop is always returning a `0` for `x`**. I am not that new to `for` loops, but I am about to scream here.

It also seems to take anything I give it and say found.

Is there an obvious problem with the `for` loop?

```
int search;
printf("what is your search: ");
gets_s(buf);
search = atoi(buf);

for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    if(search = id[x]) {
        printf("FOUND! %i", x);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use the equality operator `==`.

Comment: you are all correct. It is sometimes those little things that kick me around. I will mark correct in 5 mins, stackoverflow won't let it happen until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
if (search == id[x])
{
      printf("FOUND! %i", x);
      break;
}
```

`=` is the assignment operator. So `(search = id[x])` is true if `id[x]` is non-zero.

Whereas, `==` is the equality operator, which checks if two expressions are equal.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `=` instead of `==`. Change

```
if (search = id[x])
```

to

```
if (search == id[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

In `C` and similar languages (Java, C# etc.), `=` is not a equality test, it is assignment (i.e. setting a value). To test equality, you need to use `==`.

Thus update your code to `if (search == id[x])` if you want to check if `search` is *equal* to `id[x]`. Otherwise it returns the assignment value (i.e. `id[x]`). which is considered "true" in C if it non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

you were doing search=id[x],

initially x is 0 ,
at that point search gets the value of id[0].
if it is a non-zero value, the expression in if condition evaluates to TRUE and it will execute the body of if()
and hence it was getting terminated with wrong result

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{

    if (search == id[x])    //here is the change
    {
        printf("FOUND! %i", x);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your if condition instead of comparison

```
search == id[x]
```

you have done assignment as

```
search = id[x]
```

in c language if u do an assignment in an if condition assignment happens and than value of `search` variable in your case is passed to if condition.

In C language since a positive integer value greater than 0 is considered as true therefore your if condition satisfies and you are getting 0 as positions of your searched item every-time.